# Get record ID in Trigger.isBefore && Trigger.isInsert

Tags: apex, trigger, insert

I want to get the ID of the record in **Trigger.isBefore && Trigger.isInsert**.
I need to start a batch process based on this ID. 
It works for Trigger.isUpdate but does not work for Trigger.isInsert.

Below is my code:

```
if(Trigger.isBefore && Trigger.isInsert)
{
  onbeforeInsert((list<MyCustomObj__c>) trigger.new,(map<id, MyCustomObj__c>) trigger.OldMap);
}
```

This does not work. Can anyone please help me here?

I am getting the below exception:

> System.QueryException: invalid ID field: null

I have tried using **AfterInsert** Trigger as below:

```
 if (Trigger.isAfter && Trigger.isInsert)
 {
     onAfterUpdate((list<MyCustomObject__c>) trigger.new,(map<id, MyCustomObject__c>) trigger.OldMap);
 }

private void onAfterUpdate(list<MyCustomObject__c> lsttriggernew,map<id,MyCustomObject__c> triggeroldmap)
{            
    startBatch(lsttriggerNew,triggeroldmap);            
}
```

I have a method StartBatch where I am updating a field value of the same object.

```
public static void startBatch(list<MyCustomObject__c> lsttriggernew, map<id,MyCustomObject__c> triggeroldmap)
{
    MyField__c = 'Progress';
    //Then calling the batch job here
}
```

When I use AfterInsert Trigger, I am getting below error-

> Apex trigger caused an unexpected exception, contact your
>   administrator: execution of AfterInsert caused by:
>   System.FinalException: Record is read-only:
>   Class.TriggerHandler.startBatch

Comment: The ID doesn't exist in before insert because you haven't created the record yet.  If you want your batch to process inserted records, you have to call it from the after insert trigger.

Comment: When I try the same in AfterInsert, I am getting below error:                           
`Apex trigger caused an unexpected exception, contact your administrator: 
execution of AfterInsert caused by: System.FinalException: Record is read-only: 
Class.TriggerHandler.startBatch: line 58, column 1`

Comment: Please edit your original post to include this error message and the relevant code from your TriggerHandler that is causing the error.

Comment: Sure. I just updated the post to include all the details.

Answer (score 2):

As you've found, you don't get an Id until `after insert`, and you can only make changes to records in `Trigger.new` in a `before` trigger.  (See [documentation on Context Variable Considerations](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_triggers_context_variables_considerations.htm) for more details.)

There are several ways around this.  One way is to use DML to update the record in the `after insert` trigger.  Another way around this is a bit simpler and less likely to affect limits -- update the field in the `before` trigger, and run the batch job in the `after` trigger.  Ideally, they should be the same trigger, so it's clear what's happening.  E.g.:

```
trigger RunTheBatch on MyCustomObject__c (before insert, after insert) {
  if (Trigger.isBefore) {
    for (MyCustomObject__c mco : Trigger.new) {
      mco.MyField__c = 'Progress';
    }
  } else {
    startBatch(Trigger.new, Trigger.oldMap);
  }
}
```